# pip install produces OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python-2.7, pip, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I'm wanting to install ten packages via pip in virtualenv.

I possibly used `sudo` improperly in my haste to get it "working" as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27939356/1063287, ie I installed virtualenv with sudo:

`sudo virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV`

I did this because without sudo I got this:

```
me@my-comp:/var/www/html$ virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2364, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1144, in install_python
    mkdir(lib_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 324, in mkdir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 150, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/ENV'
```

In `Ubuntu 16.04` I cannot see "Disk Utility" to test the solution offered however.

Trying to `pip install lxml` results in this final error:

```
Command "/var/www/html/ENV/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-jcCDbh/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-_oNugl-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/html/ENV/include/site/python2.7/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-jcCDbh/lxml/
```

Whilst two other examples are below:

**pip install bottle:**

```
(ENV) me@my-comp:/var/www/html/ENV$ pip install bottle
Collecting bottle
Installing collected packages: bottle
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 322, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.pyc'
```

**pip install requests:**

```
(ENV) me@my-comp:/var/www/html/ENV$ pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 732, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 835, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1030, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 344, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 315, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.1.dist-info'
```

If I use `sudo pip install bottle`, I get:

`sudo: pip: command not found`

**Update:**

I ran this suggestion:

`$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/www/html/ENV`

and can now pip install `bottle`, `requests`, `pymongo`, `beautifulsoup4`, `Beaker`, `pycrypto` and `tldextract`.  However, `lxml` and `pillow` are failing.

**lxml fail:**

```
Failed building wheel for lxml

Command "/var/www/html/ENV/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-yHLQQe/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-hLznuQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/html/ENV/include/site/python2.7/lxml" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yHLQQe/lxml/
```

**pillow fail:**

```
Failed building wheel for pillow

Command "/var/www/html/ENV/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-IkuM34/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-60McJh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/www/html/ENV/include/site/python2.7/pillow" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-IkuM34/pillow/
```

I have tried the suggestion here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504860/1063287

for troubleshooting these remaining errors and `libxml2-dev`, `libxslt1-dev` and `python2.7-dev` are already installed.

**Update 2:**

Installed `zlib1g-dev` as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19289133/1063287

and can install `lxml` now.

Still can't install `pillow`.

**Update 3:**

Installed `libjpeg8-dev` as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582789/1063287

and can now install `pillow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a combination of this suggestion:

```
$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/www/html/ENV
```

And making sure the following packages were installed:

- python2.7-dev
- libxml2-dev
- libxslt1-dev  ( for ^, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504860/1063287)
- apache2-dev
- zlib1g-dev  (for lxml, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/19289133/1063287)
- libjpeg8-dev (for pillow, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/33582789/1063287)

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed pip?

Try installing pip by

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

,download pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ then do a 'python get-pip.py'. This will install pip

Then for the issue of permission denied use

```
$sudo chown -R $(whoami) /var/www/html/ENV
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, this seems to install pip though:  `sudo virtualenv --no-site-packages ENV`.

Comment: I applied second suggestion re: permissions and could install some packages but not all, but after some troubleshooting got them all to install - see original post for "Update".